# Force chrome to use my preferred font over the author's

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I browse the web often, and sometimes I get tired by the type of font.
I'd like to choose my own font for rendering webpages, so that it has precedence over the website font. I'm using chrome and I've accessed:
 `settings`=> `Show advanced settings…` =>`Web Content`=>`Customize fonts`
 That works only when no font was specified by the website.
 This is not from the perspective of a webdeveloper this is the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty comfortable with a chrome extension called "Read Mode" very readable. A drawback is improper display of quoted text. 
So I'm sticking with it till I find a better alternative.

**Edit:**
Find out another one, it is a JavaScript bookmarklet, put the following line in the location bar(where you put website adresses like www.site.com) and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> :

```
    javascript:Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("*"),
function(e){e.style.fontFamily ="Source Sans Pro"})
```

Replace `Source Sans Pro` with your preferred font.

If you don't want to type this every time, bookmark it and click on it whenever you try to change the font.

Comment: I guess the second approach of this answer is a nice compromise as an answer to the question above.

Comment: Three cheers to your sir/madam, Consolas all the things.

Answer (score 2):

Improved upon the accepted answer by creating a [TamperMonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) script so that it applies to all websites by default:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Force font
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Sets the font on all websites to Consolas
// @author       You
// @match        *://*/*
// @icon         https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/656/766/png-clipart-computer-terminal-computer-icons-bash-others-miscellaneous-angle.png
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("*"), function(e){e.style.fontFamily ="Consolas"})
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [Force Font](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/force-font/iidenkflofaiinggabfmdjbomolidnie?hl=en-US). It doesn't completely work for a lot of Google websites, but it's worth a try as it works for all the other sites I use.

Comment: Do you ever have problems with page layout getting garbled? I know a properly made page won't be bothered by changing the fonts, but...

Comment: @CliffArmstrong I haven't encountered that problem yet, but that doesn't mean it doesn't happen. Also, it's pretty easy to add and change fonts, so if a site did get garbled you could change the font and size.

Comment: Ad-dons security risk is not to be taken lightly especially when only reviewed by 24 user, but thanks for giving me the idea to Stylish

Comment: @Lambda7, Stylish was my first thought, but I couldn't figure out how to make a global style sheet.

Answer (score 1):

An [TamperMonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) variant with fixed width font for 'pre' and 'code' tags while the rest gets a proportional font

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Force font
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Sets the font on all websites to Consolas
// @author       You
// @match        *://*/*
// @icon         https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/656/766/png-clipart-computer-terminal-computer-icons-bash-others-miscellaneous-angle.png
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
        document.getElementsByTagName("*"),
        function(e){
            if (e.parentNode && (e.parentNode.tagName === "PRE" || 
                                 e.parentNode.tagName === "CODE")) {
                return
            }
            if (e.tagName === "PRE" || e.tagName === "CODE") {
                e.style.fontFamily = 'Go Mono'
            } else {
                e.style.fontFamily = 'Go Medium'
            }
        })
})();
```